# Inner join Logic in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am using Inner join where i want to combine 2 result to display in singel table.
I have created query to check latecoming  and earlyleaving  now i want both the output displayed as one singel table.
Query For lateComing:

```
    select k.EmpId,Min(k.DateofCheckin) as mindate,
    case 
    when min(time(DateofCheckin))<=@i then 'Ontime'
    when min(time(DateofCheckin)) between @i and @j then 'Late'
    when min(time(DateofCheckin)) between @j and @n then 'HalfDay'
    when DAYOFWEEK(Date(DateofCheckin)) =7 and  min(time(DateofCheckin)) >@j  then 'HalfDay'
    else 'Absent' end as LoginStatus
    from CheckInLogs k Join
    (select 
    @i:=time(r.LateComer) as LateComing,
    @j:=time(r.LateComingEndTime) as LateComingEnd,
    @m:=time(LunchStartTime),
    @n:=time(LunchEndTime),
    @o:=time(EarlyLeavingStartTime),
    @p:=time(EarlyLeavingEndTime), 
    e.EmpId
    FROM Employees e JOIN Profiles r ON e.LeaveProfile=r.ProfileName) h
    on k.EmpId=h.EmpId
    where k.DateofCheckin='in'  and  
    DAYOFWEEK(Date(k.DateofCheckin)) != 1 and
    k.BranchId=1 and date(DateofCheckin) between '2013-05-1' and '2013-05-29'
    group BY date(k.DateofCheckin),k.EmpId
```

Query For EarlyLeaving:

```
select 
    EmpId,Date(DateofCheckin) as LogoutDate,DateofCheckin,max(time(DateofCheckin)) as LogoutTime,
    case 
    when max(time(DateofCheckin))>=@p then 'Ontime'
    when DAYOFWEEK(Date(DateofCheckin)) =7 and  max(time(DateofCheckin)) < @m
    then 'HalfDay'
    when DAYOFWEEK(Date(DateofCheckin)) =7 and  max(time(DateofCheckin)) > @m  then 'Ontime'
    when max(time(DateofCheckin)) between @o and @p then 'EarlyLeaving'
    when max(time(DateofCheckin)) between @m  and @o then 'HalfDay'
    when max(time(DateofCheckin))<=@m then 'Absent'
    else 'Absent' end as LogoutStatus
    from CheckInLogs k1 Join
    (select 
    @i:=time(r.LateComingStartTime) as LateComing,
    @j:=time(r.LateComingEndTime) as LateComingEnd,
    @m:=time(LunchStartTime),
    @n:=time(LunchEndTime),
    @o:=time(EarlyLeavingStartTime),
    @p:=time(EarlyLeavingEndTime), 
    e.EmpId
    FROM Employees e JOIN Profiles r ON e.LeaveProfile=r.ProfileName) h1
    on k1.EmpId=h1.EmpId
    where k1.DateofCheckin='Out' 
    and k1.BranchId=1
    and DAYOFWEEK(Date(k1.DateofCheckin)) != 1 and  
    date(k1.DateofCheckin) between '2013-06-1' and '2013-06-29'
    group BY date(k1.DateofCheckin),k1.EmpId
```

Comment: if you have the same columns you can use `UNION` and a additional column that will be `early` or `late` so that you can distinguish between the results

Comment: Or you can do a join between the two table on emp id this was you will have early and late on the same row

Comment: An inner join would only give you instances where they were both late coming and early leaving. Is this what you really want? It looks to me like a union would be a better idea?

Comment: I would try 'flipping' this around start with `employees with profile` then join `CheckInLogs` twice, one for `in`, one for `out`.

Comment: can any one give me exact explain with basic query for clear understanding

Comment: Guys If i would use Union it will display in stack i want to use inner query only

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how i'd approach the query, *this was a quick copy and past job so you'd have to fix syntax errors etc*. The main difference is that you only need to get the employee details once at the start of the query and add a common field between the two current queries (other than employee) to join on. In this case I have used `logoutdate`

```
select *
from (select 
    @i:=time(r.LateComer) as LateComing,
    @j:=time(r.LateComingEndTime) as LateComingEnd,
    @m:=time(LunchStartTime),
    @n:=time(LunchEndTime),
    @o:=time(EarlyLeavingStartTime),
    @p:=time(EarlyLeavingEndTime), 
    e.EmpId
FROM Employees e JOIN Profiles r ON e.LeaveProfile=r.ProfileName) h
JOIN (select 
        EmpId, Date(DateofCheckin) as LogoutDate,
        DateofCheckin,max(time(DateofCheckin)) as LogoutTime,
        case 
            when max(time(DateofCheckin))>=@p then 'Ontime'
            when DAYOFWEEK(Date(DateofCheckin)) =7 and  max(time(DateofCheckin)) < @m
                then 'HalfDay'
            when DAYOFWEEK(Date(DateofCheckin)) =7 and  max(time(DateofCheckin)) > @m                  then 'Ontime'
            when max(time(DateofCheckin)) between @o and @p then 'EarlyLeaving'
            when max(time(DateofCheckin)) between @m  and @o then 'HalfDay'
            when max(time(DateofCheckin))<=@m then 'Absent'
        else 'Absent' end as LogoutStatus
      from CheckInLogs k1    
      where k1.DateofCheckin='Out' 
      and k1.BranchId=1
      and DAYOFWEEK(Date(k1.DateofCheckin)) != 1
      group BY date(k1.DateofCheckin), k1.EmpId) out
ON out.empid = h.empid
JOIN (select k.EmpId, Date(DateofCheckin) as LogoutDate,
                Min(k.DateofCheckin) as mindate,
                case 
                    when min(time(DateofCheckin))<=@i then 'Ontime'
                    when min(time(DateofCheckin)) between @i and @j then 'Late'
                    when min(time(DateofCheckin)) between @j and @n then 'HalfDay'
                    when DAYOFWEEK(Date(DateofCheckin)) =7 
                        and min(time(DateofCheckin)) >@j  then 'HalfDay'
                    else 'Absent' end as LoginStatus
      from CheckInLogs k Join
        where k.DateofCheckin='in'  and  
        DAYOFWEEK(Date(k.DateofCheckin)) != 1 and
        group BY date(k.DateofCheckin),k.EmpId) in
ON in.empid = out.empid
AND in.LogoutDate = out.LogoutDate
```

I would also consider moving the `case` and `group bys` to the top level query.